# Trace of an observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, observables

If $X$ and $Y$ are two observables and $\rho$ is a density operator, is it true that for every complex number $z$ the quantity 
$$
\mathrm{tr}[\rho (X+zY)^*(X+zY)]
$$
is non-negative?

Comment: As it's written, the answer is **no**.   Could it be that one of the $z$'s should be compex conjugated?

Comment: Did you intend $*$ to represent the adjoint of the matrix, or did you intend the conjugate $\dagger$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Use the  fact that the operator in the trace different from $\rho $ is positive and compute the trace using a basis of eigenvectors of $\rho $, whose eigenvalues are also positive. (By positive I actually mean nonnegative).

Here is the proof (assuming the first version of the question regarding $tr(\rho (X+zY)^\dagger(X+zY))$). As $\rho$ is self-adjoint (with pure point spectrum) it has a spectral decomposition
$$\rho = \sum_{i} p_i |\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i|$$
where
$$\rho \psi_i = p_i\psi_i$$
with $p_i \in [0,1]$, $\sum_i p_i =1$ and the eigenvectors $\psi_i$ define a Hilbert basis of the Hilbert space.

Next define $Z=X+zY$. As $X$ and $Y$ are self-adjoint (I also assume they are bounded) we have $Z^\dagger = X+z^*Y$, though this identity will not be used.

Now, exploiting  the basis of eigenvectors $\psi_i$ of $\rho$ with eigenvalues $p_i$ to compute the trace
$$tr\left(\rho Z^\dagger Z\right)= tr\left(Z^\dagger Z\rho\right)=\sum_i \langle \psi_i|Z^\dagger Z\rho \psi_i\rangle= \sum_i \langle \psi_i|Z^\dagger Z\psi_i\rangle p_i\:.$$
Since all the eigenvalues $p_i$ are non-negative, to conclude, it is enough establishing that $\langle \psi_i|Z^\dagger Z\psi_i\rangle \geq 0$. In fact,
$$\langle \psi|Z^\dagger Z\psi\rangle = \langle Z\psi|Z\psi\rangle = ||Z\psi||^2 \geq 0$$

Comment: Please, can you suggest me a book where it has been explained ..

Comment: @B.Reddy In more detail? Unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $(X + zY)^*$ is the conjugate of $X + zY$, a counter-example is:

$$z=0, Y=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}, X=\begin{bmatrix} 0&-i\\i&0 \end{bmatrix}, \rho = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2&0\\0&1/2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Because:

$tr[\rho(X+zY)^*(X+zY)]$

$= \text{Tr}\left[I/2\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0&-i\\i&0 \end{bmatrix}+0\right)^*\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0&-i\\i&0 \end{bmatrix}+0\right)\right]$

$= \text{Tr} \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0&i\\-i&0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0&-i\\i&0 \end{bmatrix}$

$= \text{Tr} \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} -1&0\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$

$= -1$

But if you intended the $*$ to refer to the *adjoint*, usually represented as $(X+zY)^\dagger$, then the trace is in fact always non-negative (as shown in the other answer).